# ffmpeg copy highest quality audio track of a specific language

Tags: ffmpeg

Say you input has 2 english audio tracks, 7.1 and 2.0.

You want to copy the audio track of highest quality (number of channels) to `audio.ext`

If I use `-map 0:m:language:eng` it selects all english audio tracks where I thought by default it would only copy the highest channel audio track.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i *mkv -map 0:m:language:eng -vn -acodec copy output.flac
```

Comment: What's your full command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `map` option will select all streams matched by the specification. The 'best' stream is only selected in the absence of any map options.

So, you'll need a two-stage process to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map 0:a:m:language:eng -vn -acodec copy -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -c copy output.flac
```

The first ffmpeg process sends all English language audio streams to the 2nd ffmpeg process, which will select only the 'best' among the received streams for output.

If you want to keep metadata, and not worry about the codec of the input file, you can change your output to `.mkv`

Comment: That's the 'file format' set for the piped data. ffmpeg generally detects the format based on the extension of the output file. There's none specified by `-` so we have to set one. `-f matroska` would work as well but nut supports finer timestamps so I prefer that.

Comment: nut is not really necessary here, just a habit for me. ffmpeg can't auto-supply extension.

Comment: I've added this to your answer so is more relevant to others. Thanks so much! I'll cleanup old comments

Comment: Trying to adapt this to subtitles doesn't work. Any idea why? `-map 0:s:m:language:eng -vn -scodec copy -f nut - | ffmpeg -f nut -i - -c:s srt "${file%.mkv}".eng.srt`

Comment: Share full log.